# VS-Code installing omnisharp error unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

When attempting to install the Omnisharp Visual code extensions on my work machine, downloading the package fails and the extension does not install.

VS-Code version: 1.27.2

When I open a c# file the output window displays

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: win32, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)'... Failded at stage: downloadPackages

Error unable to verify the first certificate
```

I haven't got a particularly detailed knowledge of my work's network and firewall setup but from reading around it is pointing towards that being the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was fixed for me by updating my settings.json file.

This file can be edited by following these steps:

1. File -> Preferences -> Settings (or press 'Ctrl + ,' on a windows setup with default key mappings)
2. The settings page now appears. Underneath the settings search bar on the right hand side is a little '...' icon. Click that and choose 'Open settings.json'

Once you have the settings.json file open you need to add a new setting, which is this

```
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

Now restart VS-code and open up a C# file and the extension should install sucessfully.

I found this information here : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/605 
The original issue was about a different extension but it worked for me